# Check if a post is in a category outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically, I want to check a post if it's in a specific category but for the life of me, I'm doing something wrong. Here's the current code

```
$post_catz = wp_get_post_categories( $this->post->ID );
$catz = array();

foreach($post_catz as $c){
    $cat = get_category( $c );
    $catz[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
    if ($catz['slug'] = 'featured') { 
        $colorslist = 'colorlistingfeat'; 
    }
}
```

`$colorslist` is a variable that I want to change, if the post is from that specific category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code having a bug in checking the array. Try this instead.

```
<?php
$post_catz = wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID());
$catz = array();

foreach($post_catz as $c){
    $cat = get_category( $c );
    $catz[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
}   

foreach($catz as $cs){
    if($cs['slug'] == 'featured') { 
        $colorslist = 'colorlistingfeat'; 
    }
}

echo $colorslist;
?>
```

But ensure that `$this->post->ID` returning post ID.

Comment: $this->post->ID returns the id, I also echoed the array as you can see in the response I gave to @AlaricB. Problem is, even with your code, it doesn't check the category correctly. Not sure what's going on

Comment: Did you tried `$cat->slug` instead of `$catz[0]['slug']`? What its returning?

Comment: I did, it returns the parent category "ico". However, I can't seem to extract a child category from that parent, I was under the impression that get_category returns all categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($catz['slug'] = 'featured') { $colorslist = 'colorlistingfeat'; }
```

For comparison operators you have to use `==` not `=`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Hope this help.

Comment: Ya, I've realised my mistake immediately after I posted this, however, it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: How is it currently doing ?

have you tried to simply echo $catz['slug'] on each iteration to see if it contains what you think it should ?

Comment: it doesn't echo anything :(

Comment: Then you should check your previous variable and so on until seing when you're not getting what you're expecting.

What about $cat ? does it contain the array you're expecting ? 

Check all your variables and you'll probably see from where it 'goes wrong'

Comment: The array is displaying correctly

 WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 13 [name] => ICO [slug] => ico [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 13 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 4 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 13 [category_count] => 4 [category_description] => [cat_name] => ICO [category_nicename] => ico [category_parent] => 0 )

Problem is, it displays only 1 category, most posts belong to multiple categories.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your code `$catz[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );`. Notice `$catz[]` is an array variable.. so you should get the slug as `$catz[0]['slug]` or else the `$catz` will just return `Null` value. Much better to edit your code as `$catz = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );`

And also notice your if statement. should be if( cond == cond )